# Access denied by copying

Tags: windows, file, permissions, copy

After many experiments with security settings and getting:

```
"you need permission to perform this action<br>
you require permission from **xxx\user** to make changes to this file"
```

I tried the following:

```
C:\folder>takeown /f "c:\software\file.exe"

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "c:\software\file.exe" now owned by user "xxx\user".

C:\folder>copy "c:\software\file.exe" "c:\Program Files (x86)\some_folder"
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

How to copy the file? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Moreover, the problem is that you don't have permission to add files to the "Program Files (x86)" folder. And that's only part of the problem. The *real* problem is that you should never go putting stuff there yourself in the first place. It's protected for a reason.

Comment: I thought it's general IT forum. There are topics related to HTML. What does it to do with programming? The "Program Files..." folder was chosen as example. The reality is - I cannot copy the file to anywhere. I cannot even change the name of the file.